# Allow iPhone application to sync with iTunes

Tags: iphone, itunes, file-sharing

In the Apps tab of iTunes, there is a 'File Sharing' section with a list of apps that can synchronize their documents with your computer. What do you need to do to tell iTunes to sync your apps Documents folder?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603865/cfbundledocumenttypes-uifilesharingenabled-issues this might explain why you are not seeing it function properly

Comment: whether can control the iTunes shared folder in the app ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `UIFileSharingEnabled` key to your Info.plist.

Comment: Anything else? I've added this to the project and it doesn't add the app to the iTunes sharing list.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 7/8 and Xcode 6:

1. Go to properties of your Target in Xcode.
2. Click the Info tab.
3. Click the + on the last line under "Custom iOS Properties."
4. Type "UIFileSharingEnabled" and press Enter.
5. It should change to "Application supports iTunes file sharing."
6. Set the Boolean value to YES.