# UIFileSharingEnabled has no effect

Tags: iphone, ios4, itunes

I've added UIFileSharingEnabled to the .plist. Per suggestions, I have:

- removed the app and redeployed it several times
- attempted to disconnect after redeploying

I have not been able to get the app visible in the File Sharing section in iTunes. On another app, this works flawlessly. The app where it doesn't work has a bit exotic internals (an easily portable game; as such, it has its own mainloop, it doesn't have a main nib, ...). The app where it does work is pretty much standard deal. Also, testing was done on two different devices: it worked on iPod Touch 4 with iOS 4.2.1, but it didn't work on iPhone 3GS with iOS 4.2.1.

Since it's a bit difficult to isolate the problem (and I could probably spend several MORE hours isolating it), is there any other known requirement to get file sharing to work?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`CFBundleDisplayName` is additionally required in the .plist. Why Apple elected to require this, I have no idea.

Comment: Is the following OK? I'm having the same problems, and `CFBundleDisplayName` is set to `<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>` and `<string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>`

Comment: That looks about right. You may want to restore other keys from template's plist that you may have removed. I'm just guessing which may be important: `CFBundleName`: `${PRODUCT_NAME}`, `CFBundleIdentifier`: `com.hindarium.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}`. Also, try entering a concrete name instead of `PRODUCT_NAME` variable, and check your `PRODUCT_NAME` variable for correctness. Otherwise, I'm out of ideas; I stumbled upon the original solution accidentally.

Comment: Not really difficult; Apple apparently just forgot to document which keys they require to exist in plist. Theoretically, you just have to add the `UIFileSharingEnabled` key into the plist and that's it. Unfortunately, when the feature depends on additional keys present in the default template, and it is not specified which keys exactly are needed, it can get a bit tricky.

Comment: It started working once I removed the spaces from my CFBundleDisplayName.