# How to enable file sharing in iPhone app using iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, itunes, file-sharing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enable file sharing for my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029916/how-to-enable-file-sharing-for-my-app)

How can i enable file sharing functionality in iPhone app. I am very curious about this to know because when i connect my iPhone with iTunes then it show me three apps. One is Skype and second one is bump and third one is my own app. My app is about augmented reality and show some videos and images on specific markers, also i did social sharing and APNS work and flurry integration that all major working in my app and I did nothing which enable this functionality but why and how this happen. Kindly let me know. This will be great for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should Enable UIFileSharingEnabled in the application plist file, Keep this value to `YES` like this then your application can share data of your application documents [image: File Share]

Comment: Yeah, it is set to yes. Thanks...

Comment: For anybody confused by this option...as stated by rickster, below, it shows up in the list of options as "Application supports iTunes file sharing" NOT UIFileSharingEnabled.

Comment: Both are same. Set the value as true

Answer (score 4):

There is an option in {projectname}-Info.plist named "Application supports iTunes file sharing".

Comment: Yeah, I was confused about the name too.  Xcode creates the {projectname}-Info.plist and according to the documentation found in this link (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009254-SW1) at build time, this file is used to generate the Info.plist file that is then included in the resulting bundle.

Answer (score 3):

Your app will appear in iTunes File Sharing if the [`UIFileSharingEnabled`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html) key is set in its Info.plist. (This appears in the Xcode editor as "Application supports iTunes file sharing ".) If this is enabled in your project and you're not sure how, either you accidentally clicked something for this in Xcode, or you're working from a project template in which it's pre-set.