# Is it possible to copy a file from the app sandbox to the app bundle?

Tags: ios, appstore-sandbox

I can do the reverse with the following: But cannot copy to the app bundle.

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,    NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

// Destination path
    NSString *fileInDocumentsPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Passwords File.txt"];
// Origin path - used when file is in bundle
    NSString *fileInBundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Passwords File" ofType:@"txt"];

// File manager for copying File in Bundle to Sandbox
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:fileInBundlePath toPath:fileInDocumentsPath error:&error];
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure writing to the bundle directory is disallowed.  It is not part of the sandbox.

Comment: an app bundle is signed, adding a file woul dbreak the signature

Comment: The bundle directory is readonly for the app.

Answer (score 7):

The application bundle is read only. It cannot be modified after you deploy the app.

Files in your app's documents folder can be accessed via iTunes if the app supports [File Sharing](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4094). Check out [How to enable File Sharing for my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029916).

Comment: That makes sense. What I am trying to accomplish is to get a backup of the file copied to my Mac. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @RonaldBledsoe, Files in your app's documents folder can be accessed via iTunes if the app supports [File Sharing](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4094). Check out [How to enable File Sharing for my app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029916/how-to-enable-file-sharing-for-my-app).