# Cocoa iTunes API in order to download a file on iPad/iPhone

Tags: ios, cocoa, itunes

I have a big problem with iTunes. I just want to put a pdf in ebook reader or fetch a pdf (mac to iPhone/iPad and iPhone/iPad to mac).

I want to write a very small and simple program that allows to read iPad content like a usb key.

Is there some iTunes API or Cocoa API to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable file sharing for my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029916/how-to-enable-file-sharing-for-my-app)

Answer (score 0):

Already answered in [How to enable file sharing for my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6029916): Open the info.plist of your application and add the following key: `Application supports iTunes file sharing` and set it's value to `true`.

For more details see the [Ray Wenderlich Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/itunes-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app) on *iTunes Tutorial for iOS: How To Integrate iTunes File Sharing With Your iOS App*