# Any way to add music to iPod library in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipod

I want to write an app to be able to transfer music between two iOS devices and put them into iOS music library. I understand that this is a violation of app store rules, but I don't want to publish it, I want to use it for my own devices. 
Is there any way to do this on a non-jailbroken device? Like a private API or modifying a file manually? (like the private API for changing brightness I found)

Comment: Have you written the code for sending data between two iOS devices yet?

Comment: Yea it's easy already wrote it.

Answer (score 2):

About the closest you're going to be able to get is to [share the files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029916/how-to-enable-file-sharing-for-my-app) so you can access them via iTunes and drag them to the library (in iTunes). Consider simply creating your own music library and player for sharing music.

Comment: Tnx for your answer. That's my last option (file sharing and my own music player), but I really want to know if there's any way to add music to iPod music library.