# Xcode - Enabling iTunes file sharing on my app but it doesn't appear in the list in iTunes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, itunes

Xcode - Enabling iTunes file sharing on my app but it doesn't appear in the list?

Followed a number of guides both on and off StackOverflow and I can't seem to get it to appear in iTunes.

[How to enable file sharing for my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029916/how-to-enable-file-sharing-for-my-app)

Does anyone have any suggestion on what else to try?

Comment: If you give some more details of what you done exactly, we might be able to help you better. What does not appear in what list? What have you exactly set in Info.plist? Have you tried removing any old version of your app completely and restarting XCode?

Comment: After a couple of hours of hunting I discovered that for some reason my "Bundle Display Name" was blank. See my answer below for details. Apparently this is also used in some other places, quite weird if you as me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a couple of hours of hunting I discovered that for some reason my "Bundle Display Name" was blank.

This can be found by selecting the "top level App name" in Xcode's Project Navigator (the left pane with all the files) and then selecting "the app name under Targets" and then going to the Info tab.

I copied ${PRODUCT_NAME} from Bundle Name and pasted it under Bundle Display Name. I ran the app again and connected it to iTunes and now my app is the appropriate iTunes File Sharing list.

See a detailed answer here:
[How to enable file sharing for my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029916/how-to-enable-file-sharing-for-my-app?lq=1)

Comment: How do you get iTunes (12) to see your debug build? Do you have to publish for ad-hoc distribution and then install via iTunes?

Comment: Well yes... either install it via ad-hoc or connect the iPad and use Xcode and debug the app directly on it, it will actually install it like a normal app first and you can see it.

Comment: Thanks, but still when I install via Xcode, iTunes does not see the app as installed on the device. Publishing for ad-hoc and then installing via iTunes is what I ended up doing...