# How to allow App Users to share files in-between each other (like share-contact)

Tags: ios, iphone, file-sharing, fileshare

My App's main function is a short-hand Note taker... Users' input is stored in a [String] and these Strings are used in a replayer to show an animated version of what was noted.

The file will contain this Array of Strings and a few thumbnail Images.

How can I allow users to share this file with a friend that has the same App? I prefer users to be able to text the file (like in contacts "Share contact") and when the receiver taps the file...The App is opened and Replayer starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this, I strongly recommend using a web service to perform the communication between applications. You can use a REST API (examples on how to develop your own API [here](http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2014/restful-web-app-node-express-mongodb/)) so your users can upload the files, and other users can download these files onto their mobile device.

If you do not want (or do not have time) to develop your own REST API, you can sign up with [Parse](https://www.parse.com) which offers several options for solving your needs (REST API, mobile SDK's, etc), with a very simple user interface. This way your information is not stored on your user's physical device, it is instead stored in a server. This enables sharing of information and/or files.

Comment: The API link is just (hola.com). So you say there are many ways to accomplish this...Do all of them involve a server (whether personal or professional)? I really would like avoid using a server if that's possible. I know of one APP I've used "PokerJournal" that uses emails to create backup/restore files which appear to be HTML when saved to my Mac but it's just a page. Is this possible without a server? or does user's email host work as the server?

Comment: I fixed the link. Sorry for that. I do not know if there is a way to transfer the files from one device to another without using a server as the middleman, I can only think of solutions using a server. With respect to the email, your email address account is just another account in the email provider's host server, so yes it would act as the server.

Comment: I found a solution that does not require use of a server. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029916/how-to-enable-file-sharing-for-my-app?rq=1

Comment: This seems to suggest using iTunes file sharing, which to my understanding is just the sharing of files between one person's computer and Device. I am interested in allowing userA to send a file from Device to userB's Device.

Comment: Then I misunderstood iTunes file sharing. I cannot think of a way of achieving this without the use of a server as a middleman.