# App appears in Open In list but not in Send Copy list

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios9

We have an application that we want to integrate with MS Excel for iPad.
We were able to associate excel files with our app by declaring Document Types in Info.plist. Our app now appears in Open In... of Numbers app and also when you click on excel file attachments in emails.

Now, we want our app to open files from the MS Excel app in iPad.
When we try Share > Send Attachment > Send a Copy,
applications such as Mail, Notes, Firefox, Evernote etc appear in the list but not our app.

How do we make our app appear in this list?

Comment: have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6029954/3755838) answer

Comment: yes, but unfortunately, it does not answer my question

Comment: As far as i know when you do "OPEN IN", your application from MSExcell, 
That document is copied to the Document directory or the sandbox of your application itself.