# iOS file transfer without AirDrop

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiactivityviewcontroller, airdrop, ios-sharesheet

I am making an iOS app where i have to transfer pdf file from iOS device to mac and windows pc. I told my client to make it for iOS device to Mac using AirDrop sharing.

But client told me that, he never wants to depend third party help. He just will send the file between mac and iPhone. He is a non tech guy. I am stuck here.

Do i have to code for own protocol or something?

Comment: What could be the best possible way ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029916/how-to-enable-file-sharing-for-my-app Check this link, hopefully it will help you. Thanks

Comment: not same. @NehaGupta