# How to access documents directory from Windows computer

Tags: ios, windows, nsdocumentdirectory

**SCENARIO**

Our application is having some difficulty on our clients system. It seems to be crashing upon login but only happens on our client's network, not ours. To troubleshoot this problem I have created a simple logging manager that will log statements to a `.txt` file and store it in the documents directory of the application. These logs will describe what action the application has taking and prints a line in the logs.

**EXAMPLE**

[image]

**QUESTION**

Typically I always access the documents directory via Xcode -> Devices -> and downloading the container to view the `AppData`. But our client is using a Windows machine and Xcode is only available for MAC.

*How do I tell our client how to access the logs on their computer in order to then email them back to me*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may switch on file sharing for your app by setting `UIFileSharingEnabled` to `YES` in app's `*.plist` ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19980303/apple-not-allow-the-app-share-document-directory-data-directly-to-user-uifiles) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029916/how-to-enable-file-sharing-for-my-app) for examples). After that your client will be able to access and extract files from the Documents directory via iTunes.

Comment: That example is just what I needed. Our .plist needs to set the `UIFileSharingEnabled` key to YES. Then our client may get the logs `.txt` from iTunes and email them to us. Perfect. Thanks.