# Save computer-accessible file from iPhone

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I would like to let a user save a file from my iOS app (Xamarin.Forms) to a computer. Since this seems impossible directly, I'd like to let him save the file on the device, so that he can then connect the device to a computer and copy it. But this seems a problem as well (except for images and videos). I tried checking iCloud, but that looks extremely complicated (and overkill).

So, is there some simple way to do this anyway? If not, is there some simple workaround? (I don't have experience with this; please don't discount any obvious solutions.)

Comment: Not specifically C# but there is iTunes file sharing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029916/how-to-enable-file-sharing-for-my-app

Comment: @rckoenes Thanks. That looks promising. I'm checking it out now. But let me confirm - that's for arbitrary file types, not just media. Correct?

Comment: Any files in the document directory will be shown in iTunes.

Comment: @rckoenes Thanks. You can transform your comments into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS offers iTunes file sharing, [How to enable file sharing for my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029916/how-to-enable-file-sharing-for-my-app)

This will show all your files in your apps document directory in iTunes. Allowing a user to add and retrieve files from your app.