# Xcode iOS 11 show folder app in app File Apple

Tags: swift, xcode, file

I can not understand how to share folders and files created by my app within Apple File app.
Virtually how does the app Pages

I tried this but it did not work
[How to enable file sharing for my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029916/how-to-enable-file-sharing-for-my-app)

Answer (score 4):

Edit your Info.plist file and add these keys:

```
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<true/>
<key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
<true/>
```

The file sharing link included in the question is for the iTunes-based file sharing, which is still supported and requires the `UIFileSharingEnabled` key only. The new Files app in iOS 11 requires that key plus the `LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace` key.