# Make iOS app's directory available for saving files (such as from Apple's Files app)

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to be able to have my app's folder available for the user to copy/save files there.

For example, if I select a photo from the gallery and choose an action to save it to Apple's Files app, I would see under "On My iPhone" a list of some apps that accept this kind of operation, such as Pages, Keynote and Numbers (this screenshot from the Simulator has none of those installed).[image: Simulator screenshot]

How would I go about making my app appear on this list?

Comment: Is this you are looking for?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029916/how-to-enable-file-sharing-for-my-app

Comment: Try enable Wallet in Capabilities.
To enable it go to Target->Capabilities->Wallet