# iOS Music started from background

Tags: ios, alarm, ios-background-mode

i'm thinking about an iOS alarm app. At the time of the alarm i want to play custom music from Apple Music or another source.

Unfortunately app background operations are really restrictive and notifications only allow bundled music files to be played. Is there any way to achieve my goal by using background tasks or something else?

Comment: You can try setting alarm in reminders application from your application this will run the music of reminder app even if you application is in background mode or suspended or terminated .......

Answer (score 0):

There're no other choices except using notifications, seealso: [Background Execution](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle/preparing_your_app_to_run_in_the_background/about_the_background_execution_sequence)

### Change the sound of notification.

#### 1. Import audio files.

- Visit the iPod music library

  ```
  let mediaquery = MPMediaQuery()
  // MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification
  if let musics = mediaquery.items {
      for music in musics {
          let title = music.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyTitle) as? String

          if let url = music.assetURL {
              saveNotificationSound(url,name: title,isLast: music == musics.last)
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  The important param is `assetURL`, you can get audio file by it. **NOTICE:** If the music is download from Apple Music or in the iCloud, it's `assertURL` is nil.
- Use file sharing
  [How to enable file sharing for my App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029916/how-to-enable-file-sharing-for-my-app?noredirect=1&lq=1)

#### 2. Cut the audio to 30s and specified format for notification

Because the notification is limited: 1. The duration is not more than 30s; 2. The format is limited, we cut it to `m4a`.

```
/**
 Cut the duration and convert to m4a, than save it. 

 - parameter audioPath:  Source file path 
 - parameter startTime:  Cut start time
 - parameter endTime:    Cut end time 
 - parameter saveDirect: ... 
 - parameter handler:    ...
 */
func cutoffAudio(audioPath: NSURL, startTime: Int64, endTime: Int64, saveDirect:NSURL, handler: (succeed: Bool) -> Void){

    let audioAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: audioPath, options: nil)

    if let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: audioAsset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A){

        let startTime = CMTimeMake(startTime, 1)
        let stopTime = CMTimeMake(endTime, 1)

        exportSession.outputURL = saveDirect
        // Output is m4a
        exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A
        exportSession.timeRange = CMTimeRangeFromTimeToTime(startTime, stopTime)

        exportSession.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler({ 
            handler(succeed: exportSession.status == .Completed)
        })
    }
}
```

#### 3. Set as the sound of notification

**Attention:** The custom audio files can only be placed in `/Library/Sounds` in App's **Sandbox**, than the `soundName` only needs to provide the file name (including the extension), the audio files are just like in the main bundle.

[Here is a demo from github.com/ToFind1991](https://github.com/ToFind1991/NotificationMusic)

The code is not compatible with the current Swift version, you need to adjust it.

Comment: Ok, that means it only works with UNNotificationRequest and bundled music files?

Comment: You can change the notification sound by audio file. @user1517039