# Unable to see SQLite file in iTunes

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sqlite

```
- (void) copyDatabaseIfNeeded
{  
    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:ABC.Sqlite];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
    if (success) return;
    // The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location.
    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:ABC.Sqlite];
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
    if (success)
    {
        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:WSURL2];

    } else
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

I need to add any code for to View Sqlite File ??

I tried by adding these in Plist: `UIFileSharingEnabled`, `CFBundleDisplayName`

How can i view my SQLIte file in iTunes ?

Referred links:
[How to enable file sharing for my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029916/how-to-enable-file-sharing-for-my-app), [UIFileSharingEnabled has no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546334/uifilesharingenabled-has-no-effect/4546581#4546581)

If i  enabled iTunes file sharing option in my app to backup app data in PC, will appStore rejects the app ?

Comment: Do you store the file in the Documents folder in your app? Show some relevant code.

Comment: i have edited the code please check once, I need to add any code for to View Sqlite File ?? @rmaddy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not creating the file in the Documents directory, but the Library directory:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
//                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You want `NSDocumentDirectory`.

Comment: Do not forget to turn off iTunes File Sharing before uploading to App Store. Otherwise your app will be rejected.