# How to share docs/pdf files from my files(iOS) in to myApp

Tags: ios, swift, file-sharing

I want to share files to my Swift app via UIActivityViewController. I tried:

```
UIFileSharingEnabled 
and 
<key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
    <string>MainInterface</string>
    <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.ui-services</string>
</dict>
```

when user tap to share any file from "My Files" app I want to show my app under UIActivityViewController and when user tap on my App i want to open that document in my App.

Comment: please give me atleast some hint

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546334/uifilesharingenabled-has-no-effect

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to share docs / PDF's but your `NSExtensionActivationRule` dictionary has an `NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount` entry.

Can you change this to `NSExtensionActivationSupportsFileWithMaxCount` and see if this works ([this is the documentation that I am referring to](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AppExtensionKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014212-SW2)).

I'm sorry I cannot give a more categorical answer because your question is sort of unclear to me. If this doesn't help, could you clarify the below things:

1. By "My Files app" are you referring to the Apple's 'Files' app, or is it a different 3rd-party app, or is it another app that you have built / are building?
2. With your existing config (`NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount` key) what is the behaviour you observe?
3. Does the behaviour change when you use the `NSExtensionActivationSupportsFileWithMaxCount` key?

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you for reply i have to share from Apple's my files to My own app.

Comment: Did you try the above suggestion..?

Comment: yes i tried the above but it is same