# Copy file to/from NSDocumentDirectory during dev

Tags: ios

I'm playing with NSDocumentDirectory and saving files on my iPhone.  I have created a dictionary and saved it successfully to NSDocumentDirectory and I can re-load it upon re-launch of my app.  However, during development I would like to actually browse and copy files to and from NSDocumentDirectory.  Is there a way via X-Code or Finder or iTunes to see the contents of my app's NSDocumentDirectory?

The real goal here to move a file generated on my iPhone to my iPad, but starting with copying back and forth from Mac to device would be great!

Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can transfer files to / from app's Document directory through the [File sharing feature](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4094) in iTunes. To do so, you have to set UIFileSharingEnabled property to YES in your app-info.plist. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603865/cfbundledocumenttypes-uifilesharingenabled-issues) if you have problems setting it up.

Answer (score 0):

Download iFunBox. It will allow you to access the IOS file system.

The latest version is [here](http://dl.i-funbox.com/ifunbox_en.zip).

Comment: That's an EXE. Is there any solution for OS X?

Answer (score 0):

[IPhoneExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iphoneexplorer/) is available for Mac and Windows.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion.  I ended up using MFMailComposeViewController to generate an email with the file as an attachment.  Then, on the other device I registered my app to handle that particular file type.  When I received the email on my iPad I was able to open the attachment in my app and play with the file over there.