# disable iTunes file sharing

Tags: ios, itunes, file-sharing

I would like to disable iTunes file sharing of my app. I went to info.plist and added an entry `UIFileSharingEnabled` equal to `NO`.

When I run the app, and go to iExplorer my apps still has visible Documnets folder Library and so on. What additional steps do I need to perform?

[image]

Comment: iExplorer does not use the iTunes file sharing, It just reads the device its file system.

Comment: You can hide your files in respected folders.

Comment: check out the image I added. What respected folders do you have in mind?

Comment: maybe try to use 
- (nullable NSURL *)containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:(NSString *)groupIdentifier of NSFileManager. But you need to enable app groups and so on.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't have to disable iTunes File Sharing, since it is disabled by default.
You're seeing the folders in iExplore since you've probably used XCode to install the app on the device (all apps installed not from the AppStore will still have visible folders). So for all apps installed from the AppStore the folders will be hidden, unless the developer explicitly enables iTunes File Sharing.

Comment: Does it also mean for apps distributed through `AdHoc`, it will also have visible folders?

Comment: From my experience - YES